# My Code not working C# .NetCore Saving Data to data using Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, .net-core, logic

I'm trying to save multiple data from the list i created and so I created a foreach loop

```
foreach (var jline in jobline)
{
    var pjobline = new PrintJobLine();

    pjobline.PrintJobId = pjguidno; // jline.PrintJobId;
    pjobline.LineIndex = jline.LineIndex;
    pjobline.Text = jline.Text;
    pjobline.PrintOptions = jline.PrintOptions;
    pjobline.ItemName = jline.ItemName;
    pjobline.Quantity = jline.Quantity;

    _posContext.PrintJobLines.Add(pjobline);
                    

    _posContext.SaveChanges();
}

transaction.Commit();
result = true;
```

The Process Finished Without any error on the code but When I check on my Database Table the Data is not saved it is empty.
I'm doing this in .Net Core C#.

Comment: "but When I check on my Database Table" - OK; how are you doing that? what is the database? is it dedicated server based, or it is file-based? if it is file based, are you looking at the right file? A **very** common mistake here is to overlook that when you run an app via the DB that has file-based databases, the **files are re-copied**, and the app writes to a separate file than the one in the source directory

Comment: Could u please show the way u create transaction? Also, using a loop here is extremely inefficient. Why don't you just create a list of PrintJobLine? Then u can just use _posContext.PrintJobLines.AddRange(list); and stick all the data into the DB in one go.

Comment: Can you show commit method of transaction?

Answer (score -3):

I have faced same problem before, mostly due to data you are trying to save; if it not right EF core will not raise an exception. So, check fields in PrintJobLines table which is required and has no default value, data type and length

Comment: If Entity Framework doesn't save the data successfully, it will definitely throw an exception.

Comment: You are write, but if the exception inside an async method, you will not see it

Comment: Only if you are also doing async wrong too.

Comment: True, he should isolate the persisting code out of transaction and any async calls